# Editing EDIT causes program crash

Tags: c++, winapi, crash

I've problem with Editing EDIT window (both by writing or sending text to it). 
[Here's my code](http://pastebin.com/ZBQ6TTGN).

Few days ago i had problem for which solution was deleting MSG handling loop from new windows.
Everything would be fine, but it caused another problem. I can't edit EDIT windows.
When that handling loop is in new window Editing works, when not it doesn't.

Parent window - MainWindow
Child windows - ChatWindow

There's very few tutorials about Winapi, so sometimes i have to use code that i don't fully understand(like 2 Wndproc methods to handle window action's)

Thank's for your time

Comment: It looks to me like you're a bit too lost for an answer here to really help much. I'd considers starting with a copy of *Programming Windows, 4th Edition* (by Charles Petzold). Be aware that there are newer editions, but they mostly deal with .net, not the Windows API, so they probably don't fit what you want to do.

Comment: That pointer in `main` isn't necessary and your include guard is a reserved identifier. That was just 2 seconds of me looking. To add on, `windowTitle = ss.str().c_str();` will also cause you problems.

Comment: @chris Ironic then that the actual problem was Sorontur not using a pointer where he should have used one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK here's the problem, this

```
ChatWindow::ChatWindow()
{
    ...
    window = CreateWindowEx( WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE, 
        NazwaKlasy,windowTitle,WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW,
        CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT,DEFAULT_WIDTH , 
        DEFAULT_HEIGHT, NULL, NULL, hIns, this );
    ...
```

and this

```
okna.push_back(ChatWindow(dwSel,(char*)chBuffer));
```

In the `ChatWindow` constructor you store the this pointer (see the last parameter to `CreateWindowEx`). But when you save the `ChatWindow` object you save a *copy* in the okna vector. So the address of the `ChatWindow` object passed to `CreateWindowEx` is not the same as the address of the `ChatWindow` object in your vector.

Instead of `std::vector<ChatWindow> okna;` you should have a vector of pointers `std::vector<ChatWindow*> okna;`. That should fix the problem.

The basic issue with your design is that your window objects are not copyable because you are telling Windows what the `this` pointer is. You should add a private copy constructor and assignment operator to stop you copying them by mistake, like this.

```
class NewWindow
{
private:
  NewWindow(const NewWindow&); // prevent copying
  NewWindow& operator=(const NewWindow&); // prevent copying
};
```

Oh, and I second what Jerry says, get a copy of Petzold.

Comment: Now it doesn't crash when i edit it by typing but i can't settext by function so it did work in 50%. Also compilator warn me about: "warning: taking address of temporary" at line with okna.push_back(&ChatWindow(dwSel,(char*)chBuffer));

Comment: `okna.push_back(&ChatWindow(dwSel,(char*)chBuffer));` is no better than before. You *must* allocate with new `okna.push_back(new ChatWindow(dwSel,(char*)chBuffer));` so that your window object doesn't get destroyed. I sense you're learning C++ programming at the same time as Windows programming.